# How to pass fetcher to ApolloClient()?

Tags: node.js, react-apollo

How I can pass an instance of `node-fetch` to `ApolloClient()` imported from `apollo-boost`?

**Background:** I have an React app that works fine locally on the development server. However, when I deploy to Heroku, the app crashes and logs the following:

```
fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed, to fix pass a fetch for
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494156+00:00 app[web.1]: Error:
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494158+00:00 app[web.1]: your environment like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch.
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494159+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494160+00:00 app[web.1]: For example:
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494162+00:00 app[web.1]: import fetch from 'node-fetch';
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494163+00:00 app[web.1]: import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494164+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494165+00:00 app[web.1]: const link = createHttpLink({ uri: '/graphql', fetch: fetch });
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494167+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.checkFetcher (/app/node_modules/apollo-link-http-common/src/index.ts:175:11)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494168+00:00 app[web.1]: at createHttpLink (/app/node_modules/apollo-link-http/src/httpLink.ts:44:3)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494169+00:00 app[web.1]: at new HttpLink (/app/node_modules/apollo-link-http/src/httpLink.ts:238:11)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494171+00:00 app[web.1]: at new DefaultClient (/app/node_modules/apollo-boost/src/index.ts:105:22)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494172+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app/app.js:22:22)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494173+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494174+00:00 app[web.1]: at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494176+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494177+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-07-10T07:36:43.494178+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

I'm pretty sure I understand what's going on here. I can't, however, figure out how and where I should pass `fetch` in my current code since I'm using `ApolloClient()` and thus not touching `createHttpLink()` anywhere. I tried passing it along with the `uri` but nothing changed:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
/* Some trivial imports & code omitted */


const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'http://recoverwww-dev.herokuapp.com/graphql' : 'http://localhost:1337/graphql',
  fetch,
});

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <div id="app">
          <Menu />
          <Header />
          <div id="content">
            <Router />
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this at all using `ApolloClient()` or should I change my implementation completely? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApolloClient` component from `apollo-boost` cannot be used if custom fetcher needs to be used. The component must be then created using the `apollo-client` package. The code below is pasted from Apollo's docs with `node-fetch` appended.

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


const uri = 'address';


export default new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
          console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
          ),
        );
      if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    }),
    new HttpLink({
      uri,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      fetch,
    })
  ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

browser native fetch, but server havent. 
try this:

```
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const link = createHttpLink({
      fetch,
      uri: 'uri',
    });
```

or this:

```
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-boost'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

const link = new HttpLink({
  fetch
})
```

Comment: This is what the error msg and Apollo docs say. However, I cannot figure out where to pass `fetch` since I’m not using `createHttpLink()` anywhere. So the question is, can I somehow pass the fetcher to `ApolloClient()` or `<ApolloProvider>` or do I need to change my approach? I’ll edit the original post for clarity later. Thanks!